If a wff is satisfable in P, then it is also satisfable in K?
K-standard propositional modal logic (K) is an extension of classic Propositional Logic (P). I have a doubt about the relations between K and P.
Is there some principle that says that, being given a non-modal wff, $\varphi$, if there is an interpretation,$ \mathcal{I}$,  such that $\mathcal{I}(\varphi)=1$ (in P), then there is a model, $ \mathcal{M}$, and a world, $w$, such that $ \mathcal{M}, w \vDash \varphi_K$? Or, rather, if $\varphi$ is satisfable in P, then it is also satisfable in K? I think it is intuitive but I don't know if this intuition has some logical ground.

Please do not use MathJax, this site does not process it.

Voting to close because the math is unreadable.

Suppose I(phi) = 1. Then consider the frame with only one world that agrees with I everywhere.
ie, V(w, sentence) := I(sentence). It follows easily by definition of the forcing relation that M,w forces phi.
More generally, you may be interested in the notion of model theoretic conservative extensions.
